# Scatter Chart with lots of data - Help needed in structuring the input

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I am looking for your help.

If you look at this image below, you see that I have a Scatter Chart with Lines with 4 series.  Each of the data in each series is different.  But in summary it has (a) Key Event Marker (b) Y-Axis figure (c) Axis Figure.

The series data is sourced from a database record.  One record per series.  And each record can have a maximum of 8 events.

The challenge I have is that this simple dummy chart I manually created and linked all the series.

**The database has 500+ records and I want the ability of showing ALL the data or some of the data based on criteria.**

I have no idea how to do this.  I believe this is made more difficult as Scatter Chart is not part of PivotCharts etc.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahDpt.png)
Can you please please help.

Comment: It's difficult to determine what you are trying to do. I read this as "I have 500 series that I want to plot". That would be unreadable.

Comment: If one record is per series and there are 500+ data ranges with titles like the image shown, even by recording a macro for one data range to make one series, it takes a lot of time to create this chart. Hope someone could provide the macro code.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem. I don't know in which format you extract the data (one csv file per set?) but it might be easiest to just plot it in matlab or python / numpy. You would lose the convenience factor for GUI filtering though, but have much better analyses tools at your disposal. It all depends on your requirements and abilities.

Excel solution:
If you can arrange your data like this, plotting is done all at once. Plus you can use the normal filter to filter and sort by data set or event etc. An additional constraint in Excel is the number of series on one graph if limited to 255. Perhaps you can split it across two graphs?

[image: Excel multiple series on single x axis]

Comment: Oh and if you really need everything on one graph, there is a way. Use one series. In the example above, put y1, y2 and y3 all in one column y. The connected lines will form a zig-zag through all three sets (in one colour). To get a break in the lines, just insert a blank row between sets.